# BusinessObjects error while trying to use "OR" function

Tags: function, expression, business-objects

The formula is found below:

```
=NoFilter(Count([Same Day];All) Where ([Person Location- Facility (Curr)]="FH ORL") 
Where ([Order Catalog Short Description]="Physical Therapy For Whirlpool Wound Care Evaluation And Treatment") 
Or ([Person Location- Nurse Unit (Curr)] InList ("7TWR";"RIO1";"GT12";"GT14";"9TWR";"XTWR";"RIO")))
```

Error Message:

> The expression or sub-expression at position 10 in the 'Or' function uses an invalid data type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of your formula is:

```
Nofilter (xxx) Where (yyy) Or (zzz InList(aaa))
```

It's complaining because it sees `yyy` as the only parameter to `Where()`.  The structure should look like:

```
Nofilter (xxx) Where (yyy Or zzz InList(aaa))
```

So try:

`=NoFilter(Count([Same Day];All) Where ([Person Location- Facility (Curr)]="FH ORL") Where ([Order Catalog Short Description]="Physical Therapy For Whirlpool Wound Care Evaluation And Treatment" Or [Person Location- Nurse Unit (Curr)] InList ("7TWR";"RIO1";"GT12";"GT14";"9TWR";"XTWR";"RIO")))`